# gradle CompileJava task is not respecting the (source|target)Compatibility properties, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: bad major version

Tags: java, compiler-construction, gradle

I am trying to compile an application to be compatible with Java 1.6 and thought that to do so i must set the targetCompatibility to '1.6', however when I deploy the application (appserver runs with jvm 1.6) and attempt to start it, I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/foo/SomeClass, offset=6
```

My JAVA_HOME is set to 1.7, but I am maintaining two branches of source code, one that supports java 1.7 and one that supports 1.6 so would rather not have to set the JAVA_HOME variable everytime i switch contexts.

1. Is this a bug in gradle?
2. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Lol. One minute i ask this question and the next minute i solve it. the reason was because i was calling the gradle script through the git bash terminal which sets it's own java_home variable. when i opened a vanilla command prompt and ran the build, the task threw Java 1.6 errors (an exception at diamond syntax). Nevermind :)